# invalid url(404 domain subdirectories) redirect to domain using apache2 without using .htaccess

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, redirect, digital-ocean, proxy-server

i looking for  redirect 404 subdirectory urls to homepage using apache2 000-default.conf file

web server is jboss and port is 8080 and apache2 using port 80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain.com/MobApp/
 ServerAlias domain.com/MobApp/*
 RedirectPermanent / /domain.com/MobApp

ServerAlias www.domain.com/MobApp domain.com/MobApp  
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080//MobApp
ProxyPassReverse /  http://127.0.0.1:8080//MobApp


ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
ProxyRequests Off 

DocumentRoot /usr/local/share/jboss/welcome-content/MobApp

</VirtualHost>
```

without using .htaccess file is it possible?

Comment: `ServerName domain.com/MobApp/` is wrong. Can you show with examples what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: @Andra i have subdirectory domain.com/MobApp.  i want to redirect  404 status pages to fixed url